# changed object structure from item with object to array of objects in MongoDB shows error "An error occurred while deserializing"

Tags: mongodb

[image]
I have changed the object structure from

```
{
  id:"...",
  name:"...",
  url:"...",
  studentAccess:{
    "A":"....",
    "B":"...",
  },
  ecosystemId:"..."
}
```

TO:

```
{
  id:"...",
  name:"...",
  url:"...",
  studentAccess:[
    {
      "X":"....",
      "Y":"..."
    },
    {
      "X":"....",
      "Y":"..."
    },
    {
      "X":"....",
      "Y":"..."
    },
  ],
  ecosystemId:"..."
}
```

in API we get list of these objects based on ecosystemid or student access item "X", name or any field..calling like this in API

```
var acc = await _eco.FindByUser();

var query = await _db.CourseDocuments.FindAsync(w => w.EcosystemId == acc.Identifier);
```

after query executes i get this error pls help me i need to change structure anywhere after it changed in mongoDB?

Comment: some more information,  the courseDocument structure looks liks

Comment: CourseDocument  {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; 
        public Dictionary<string, long> StudentAccess { get; set; }
        public string EcosystemId { get; set; }
        public CourseDocument()
        {
            AdditionalAccessEmails = new HashSet<string>();
            StudentAccess = new Dictionary<string, long>>();
        }
    }